# Is there a way to convert OwinRequest to HttpRequestBase?

Tags: c#, owin

I'm writing a piece of Owin Middleware, where I need to use some legacy code, which uses HttpRequestBase as method argument. The legacy code does not follow SOLID so It's impossible to extend it to use OwinRequest instead of HttpRequestBase

Is there an extension (or a way) to convert an OwinRequest into a HttpRequestBase?

Comment: Wasn't the whole purpose of creating HttpContextBase and those classes so they would all have a common base?  Now they created an entirely new set of Owin classes.  Come on Microsoft.....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have access to the `IOwinContext` of the request, you can use this little hack to get the `HttpContextBase`:

```
HttpContextBase httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
```

And then, you would just:

```
HttpRequestBase httpRequest = httpContext.Request;
```

Comment: I don't have the IOwinContext. I'm intentionally writing middleware which doesn't inherit from OwinMiddleware. Is there any way to create an IOwinContext from the IDictionary<string, object> ?

Comment: Accepting this as an answer since OwinContext c-tor takes the IDictionary<string, object> argument and is easily create-able from the Owin environment. :) Thank you Mati.