# How to get HttpRequestBase from IOwinContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I started using Owin self host for my API and now I'm trying to fix some tests, which started to fail, because Owin does not support `HttpContext.Current`

Now I'm stuck in getting `HttpRequestBase` from `IOwinContext`. Here's my old code, which I used before Owin:

```
public static HttpRequestBase GetRequestBase(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    return ((HttpContextWrapper)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request;
}
```

And here's my try based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592374/4629531):

```
public static HttpRequestBase GetRequestBase(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var context = request.GetOwinContext();

    HttpContextBase httpContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName); // <---- Returns null

    return httpContext.Request;
}
```

The problem is that `httpContext` variable returns `null` and I don't know what's wrong.

**Does anybody know how to get HttpRequestBase using Owin?**

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and use the immediate window to poke around the context object?  I assume context is not null, but obviously the Get cannot find a HttpContextBase class in it.  I suggest A) explore context object for what you want, then B) go back to your request object and find another way to get what you want.

Comment: @AdamHeeg I tried to do that, but like vendettamit already explained OwinContext doesn't have HttpContext so I have to figure out how to change my tests, that they do not require HttpRequestBase anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you must be using System.web hosting for your webApi which is why your tests were running. Now since you have started using the OwinSelf hosting the HttpContext is no more in the picture. That's the reason you are getting null.

This is the reason we have extension methods to get OwinContext from HttpContext/Requests but there's no extension method to get the HttpContext from OwinContext.

Unfortunately you have to remove/change the above test for Self hosting.